# problem updating user space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1

Tags: wireless, networking, updates, update-manager

while updating software on Ubuntu 14.02 LTS using Software Updater, I am having problem.

There is 62.6 MB of update available, but after opening the Software Updater window, it shows all updates checked except one

> User space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator

[image: Software Updater screenshot]

check box for this update is grayed out and unable to select this update to download.

After clicking Install Now leaving that update unchecked, it gives error just after.

[image: error screenshot]

I have also tried the command line

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I still don't know to solve this grayed out check box problem but if you want to have update version of this software, here is the solution:-

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager(or any package manager you prefer)
2. Search hostapd and uninstall it.
3. Then re-install the package and newly installed package will be the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

#### What I did:

I opened Ubuntu Software Center and searched for "User space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator" and found that it's called `hostapd`. I clicked on "Remove" to uninstall it, and a prompt showed up saying that I need to uninstall `ap-hotspot` too. It's an app to turn your computer into a WiFi hotspot, much like Windows' Connectify. I let `ap-hotspot` be uninstalled along with `hostapd`. I searched for `hostapd` and installed it (again). Problem solved. Then I installed `ap-hotspot` too. Yay.

For anyone reading this, check if you use `ap-hotspot`. If you are, probably that's the problem. If you are not, search for a solution elsewhere; this answer is useless to you.

#### Edit:

`ap-hotspot` doesn't work when you update `hostapd`, must be buggy. You might want to think over it again, if you want to update it or not. Depends on how important `ap-hotspot` is to you.