# Security update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, updates, security, update-manager

When ever I run **Software Updater**, I get the following security update option `User space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator`
[image]

However I cannot select this update and after installation of other updates, I get the message that Ubuntu is up to date on my system.Also updating from terminal does not rectify this situation.I am confused about this. Please someone explain me why I cannot select this update and why I get the message that everything is up to date?

My question might be a duplicate of [problem updating user space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555744/problem-updating-user-space-ieee-802-11-ap-and-ieee-802-1) but it does not have an accepted answer and so I am asking again.

**UPDATE**
Doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not rectify the situation

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: No but will it help?

Comment: It should help.

Comment: It ran the command but there was no mention of the above update.

Comment: If it doesn't, the problem may go away in a day or two. Ubuntu doesn't usually have out-of-sync package versions, but it's been known to happen.

Comment: This thing is happening for a long time(>6 months)

Comment: @Raphael Today again I got the same thing, even after running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as suggested by you.